# unable to create a dynamic link in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a begiiner in RoR. I am trying to create links on a page. I want multiple links on the page and pass a parameter to link's url based on which link was clicked.

I tried doind this:

routes.rb:

```
get '/search/facet/:param' => 'product_search#facet'
```

view:

```
<%= link_to "MORE", /search/facet/(param => taxon)
```

product_search_controler.rb:

```
def facet
    @facetVariable = "hello"
    @taxonVariable = params[:param]
end
```

But whenever I click on the `MORE` link, I get a 404. Also, the linked page has url `/search/facet` and not `/search/facet/param=taxon` which I want.

Please could someone point out my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```
get '/search/facet/:param' => 'product_search#facet', :as=>:search

<%= link_to "MORE", search_url(:param => taxon)
```

Comment: Also,if you want taxon as a string, you need to use <%= link_to "MORE", search_url(:param => 'taxon')

Comment: This gives '/search/facet/taxon` and not `search/facet/param=taxon`. Will I still be able to use params[:param] to get the value of taxon in the controller?

Comment: Yes you will. The PARAM in the Route pattern is a place holder. You can use params[:param] to get the value 'taxon'. Give it a shot buffy.

Comment: it shows nil on the view, my view is '/product_search/facet.html.erb'. `<h1><%=@facetVariable.inspect%></h1>
<h2><%=@taxonVariable.inspect%>`. It is showing nil for both variables

Answer (score 2):

You can use named routes:

```
get '/search/facet/:param' => 'product_search#facet', :as => :product_search_facet
```

and in your view, assuming `taxon` is a local variable:

```
<%= link_to 'MORE', product_search_facet_path(taxon) %>
```

Rails guides, for reference:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html